# Is it possible to get Views data in the views-view.html.twig file?

Tags: views, theming

I see this template just uses

```
{{ rows }}
```

Is it possible to get values from the views fields in this file?

Answer (score 0):

Enable the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and use dpm().